# Statistical methods in tableone in r for categorical variable stratification

Tags: r

Does anyone know what statistical test the package uses to obtain p values when stratifying by a categorical variable with more than 2 values?

For example if I use:

```
#Coded index takes 1/2/3 depending on specific treatment given
CreateTableOne(vars, data = tab1db, factorVars = CatVars, strata = "Coded_index")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documents and the source code, it defaults to a Fisher exact test if there are fewer than 20,000 meaurements, and a Chi-square test if there are more than that. However, you can specify the default exact test, the default approximate test, and the threshold between which they are used, by passing in the parameters `testApprox`, `testExact` and `argsExact` to `CreateTableOne`

Comment: Thanks! How is this working with consecutive variables?

Comment: @EdiItelman I'm not sure what you mean. If you have two variables `var1` and `var2` which are factors with 2 and 3 levels respectively, then if you `table(var1, var2)` you will get a table with two rows and three columns. You can then do a `fisher.test` or `chisq.test` on the resultant table. It doesn't have to be a 2x2 table for these tests to be valid.